Eigenvectors of two commuting diagonalizable matrices when the eigenspaces need not have dimension one
Let $A,B$ be commuting diagonalizable $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb C$. Suppose that the eigenvalues of $A$'s are all distinct (so the eigenspaces have dimension one), and the same for $B$. Then any eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $B$, and conversely. This can be proved as follows: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with $Av=cv$, then $ABv=BAv=cBv$ so $Bv$ is an eigenvector (if it is nonzero) of $A$ with eigenvalue $c$. Since the eigenspace of $c$ is 1-dimensional, $Bv=av$ for some $a\in \Bbb C$, so $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$.
I've used the fact strongly that the eigenspaces are 1-dimensional. Is there a counterexample in the case where the eigenspaces are not necessarily 1-dimensional, that $A,B$ are commuting diagonalizable matrices but they have different eigenvectors?

Please tell me if I am understanding your question correctly. Are you asking whether there exist commuting diagonalizable matrices $A$ and $B$ and some vector $v$ which is an eigenvector of $A$ but not an eigenvector of $B$?

@terran Yes, that is exactly I was looking for.

Take $A$ to be the identity matrix and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB = BA$ and the $1$-eigenspace of $A$ is $2$-dimensional. In this case, $A$ and $B$ have different eigenvectors. For example, $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ but not of $B$.
